# Different permissions for different groups on one folder in OpenBSD?

Tags: permissions, chmod, openbsd

Is it possible to have filesystem permission ACL's (or similar) in OpenBSD? I'm trying to make a folder where one group has read-write access while a different group has read-only access. I don't want to give world read access, and I don't want to limit write access to a single user, so both need to be controlled by group permissions.

Edit: It has been suggested that OpenBSD may not have ACL's at all. Which is fine. The question remains: How can I, or is it even possible, set folder permissions in OpenBSD such that One group has write access, a different group has read-only access, while the world has no access?

Comment: Does OpenBSD even have ACLs? Last I heard, they were dead set against adding them. Along with [many other things](http://allthatiswrong.wordpress.com/2010/01/20/the-insecurity-of-openbsd/) that might make it a reasonably secure operating system.

Comment: @MichaelHampton That's kind of what I'm asking here...

Comment: The point is, if you decided on OpenBSD because of the whole "security" hype, you almost certainly chose the wrong OS.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Ah, I see. Thank you for your opinion. However, that has nothing to do with what I am asking here, which is quite simply how I can (if it is even possible) assign different permissions to a folder based on group membership.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, you're wrong.  How is not having the latest knobs and bells and whistles make OpenBSD less secure?  Complexity is what makes most systems exploitable and insecure.  ACL is not a security feature, but ASLR definitely is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

Here's an example of how you can figure it out with [Super User's BSD Cross Reference](http://BXR.SU).

You can start with the `open()` function, which is a system call, so, it's defined with a `sys_` prefix in the kernel.  Search for `sys_open`.  You'll find it at http://bxr.su/OpenBSD/sys/kern/vfs_syscalls.c#sys_open.

If you follow `sys_open()` long enough, you'll find that there's http://bxr.su/OpenBSD/sys/kern/vfs_vops.c#VOP_ACCESS.

In `VOP_ACCESS()`, you'll see that each filesystem has it's own `*_access` function to check the permissions, which is a pointer stored in `v_op->vop_access`.

Searching for `vop_access` references, you can find all the individual access functions of the filesystems.  For UFS, it's http://bxr.su/OpenBSD/sys/ufs/ufs/ufs_vnops.c#ufs_access.

In `ufs_access()`, you can see that it calls back into the shared filesystem-independent code to verify the permissions — http://bxr.su/OpenBSD/sys/kern/vfs_subr.c#vaccess.

With `vaccess()`, you can see for yourself how permissions are verified.

What you want to do is not possible in OpenBSD, because it doesn't have ACLs.

As a workaround, you could share a user/group, and implement your ACL policy through [sudo](http://mdoc.su/o/sudo) and some custom-made scripts.